# How to extend emqx clientInfo to get more fields during HTTP Authorization

Tags: erlang, mqtt, emqx

I have emqx running in docker and i`m using a .net api as HTTP Authorization service (https://www.emqx.io/docs/en/latest/access-control/authz/authz.html).

I want to know if there is a way to get more fields into the authorization endpoint of my .net api other than the ones mentioned in https://www.emqx.io/docs/en/latest/access-control/authz/authz.html (clientId, userName, etc.) .

I would like, for example to get a ${password} (exactly like we get out of the box when we setup an HTTP Service to handle authentication (https://www.emqx.io/docs/en/latest/access-control/authn/http.html).

Another example would be to get the payload of a publish request (e.g.: ${payload}).

Is this even possible? Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Regards

Comment: You appear to be conflating Authentication and Authorization. You shouldn't need the password as part of the Authorization phase as the user has already been authenticated at that point. And why do you want the payload?  It may help if you describe the problem you are trying to solve in the question.

Comment: Please, nevermind the actual business case of what we are trying to achieve. The essence of my question is: is it possible to extend the clientInfo (i think that is what the object is called) to add more fields so that the HTTP server can get other fields (other than the ones listed in the emqx documentation)?

Comment: What you are asking for is outside the MQTT Authentication/Authorisation model, Authorization should **ONLY** depend on who the user is and the topic in question. I asked about the underlying problem to try and work out if what you want will ever work.

Comment: we want to pass in a jwt token in the ${password} during the authorization flow. the HTTP authorization server will connect to our authorization server to see if the user related to the bearer token has the right claims to perform the publish or subscribe operation set in the ${topic} variable. it doesnt need to be called ${password} since stricly speaking its a token that we will pass in. however, none of this matter as all i want to know for now is if it is even possible to extend the clientInfo object.

Comment: This does help, because you could pass the jwt token as the username not the password and it would be available in both

Comment: we were planning on using the ${username} to hold the id of the tenant of the user. our tokens return claims for a user based on a tenant. right now im using the ${username} with the id of the tenant and the jwt token concatenanted but it would be much nicer if it was separate fields. another approach would be to always have the id of the tenant in the route but this would require changing all our topics to contain the id of the tenant which we dont want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution, we decided to not use emqx. We are using mqttnet.Server library where we can easily send the token and any other information on each publish and subscribe in the UserProperties

on the client side:

```
    var message = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
        .WithTopic(topic)
        .WithPayload(payload)
        .WithRetainFlag()
        .WithQualityOfServiceLevel(MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.ExactlyOnce)
        .WithUserProperty("token", token)
        .WithUserProperty("otherInfo", otherInfo)
        .Build();
    await _mqttClient.PublishAsync(message);
```

and for the subscribe:

```
    var subscribeOptions = _mqttFactory.CreateSubscribeOptionsBuilder()
        .WithTopicFilter(topic, MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce)
        .WithUserProperty("token", token)
        .WithUserProperty("otherInfo", otherInfo)
        .Build();

    await _mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(subscribeOptions);
```

The user properties are available on the Server side through:

for publish, in the InterceptingPublishAsync event handler we get the UserProperties in the

```
 InterceptingPublishEventArgs.ApplicationMessage.UserProperties
```

for subscribe, in the InterceptingSubscriptionAsync event handler we get the UserProperties in the

```
 InterceptingSubscriptionEventArgs.UserProperties
```